# How do I get user input when starting a batch file and how to separate input into difrent variables

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to lern how to make batch files, and decided to make a simple calculator, and I want it to take user input when it starts but I don't know how to make it work.
What I mean is I write:
`calc 25 * 78`
and it outputs me the result without asking for the arguments again.

The way I coded it I need the arguments to be seperated aka: each number and operator have thier own variable and the only way I was able to do that so far is if numbers have set length.

Here is my code in case it might help:

```
@echo off

set /p Action= podaj dzialanie 

set number1= %action:~2,1%
set number2= %action:~4,1%

set operation= %action:~0,1%

set /a result= number1 %operation% number2 
echo %number% %operation% %number2%=%result%
```

Comment: As a starting point, after `set /P Action=...` you could put `for %%I in (%Action%) do echo %%I` to split the input text...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand how you're intending to use the script, so this is one idea:

```batch-file
@Echo Off

:PoprosDzialanie
For %%G In (Action Integer1 Operator Integer2 Result)Do Set "%%G="
Set /P "Action=podaj dzialanie "
If Not Defined Action GoTo PoprosDzialanie
Call :AnalizujArgumenty %Action%
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo PoprosDzialanie
Set /A result=Integer1 %Operator% Integer2 
If Defined Result (Echo %Integer1% %Operator% %Integer2% = %Result%
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 3 /NoBreak>NUL)
Rem Your script continues between this line and the next none empty line.

GoTo :EOF

:AnalizujArgumenty
If Not "%4"=="" Exit /B 1
If "%3"=="" Exit /B 1
2>NUL Set /A Integer2=%3
If ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B 1
If Not "%2"=="*" If Not "%2"=="/" If Not "%2"=="+" If Not "%2"=="-" Exit /B 1
Set "Operator=%2"
2>NUL Set /A Integer1=%1
If ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B 1
Exit /B
```

The input is sent to `:AnalizujArgumenty` where each argument is analysed to ensure that only three arguments were passed and that those arguments were valid, i.e integer operator integer, *(where operator can be only `*`, `/`, `+`, or `-`)*. If those pass analysis the variables are defined, and your calculation is performed, otherwise they're undefined and the action prompt is repeated.

If you have other actions to perform in your script, those can be added where `Rem`arked, *(you may optionally delete the `Rem`ark)*.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy when you rely on correct parameters:

```
@echo off
set /a "result=%*"
echo Result is %result%
```

Works with or without spaces:

```
test.bat 5 + 3
test.bat 3*4
```

A bit more code, if you want to ask the user when there are no parameters:

```
@echo off
if "%*"=="" goto :AskUser
set /a "result=%*" || goto :AskUser
echo Result is %result%
goto :eof

:AskUser
REM no or invalid parameter(s)
echo some explanation of what input is expected.
set /p "Action= podaj dzialanie : "
set /a "result=%action%" || goto :AskUser
echo Result is %result%
```

`%*` is "all parameters". (`%1` is the first parameter, `%2` the second, etc. until `%9`, if you want to check each parameter, but then you lose the advantage to omit the spaces)